# Concise property in dart

Tags: javascript, dictionary, dart

Dart newbie here.
Kyle (or whoever) defines this javascript example here:

```
let myVar = true;
let obj = {
  myVar,
};
```

like "concise properties": https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch2.md#concise-properties

Do we have something similar with Maps in Dart?

If I do that in Dart I obtain, of course, a List instead of a Map with that value and the same key

Comment: Reading the dart docs, there doesn't seem to be any "implicit" way to accomplish what you're looking for. That may be an interesting language feature to propose them, though.

Comment: can you link me somewhere where I can propose this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think this belongs to the **dart-lang/language** github repository, it's likely the correct place to ask for such implementation: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues